# How can I create a program, where the user inputs an integer and it outputs a 90 degree number pyramid?

Tags: c++

I already have a bit, however I have no idea what to do from where I am. 
This is what I am trying to do.

ex.

Input: 5

Output:

5

44

333

2222

11111

This is my current code:

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
int a;
int counter = 1;
int counter4;
int counter5;
cout << "Enter an integer, any integer" << endl;
cin >> a;
cout << a << endl;
cout << endl;
while(a >= counter){
    counter5 = a--;
    counter4 = a;
    while(counter4 > counter5){
        cout << counter5;
        cout << "   " << endl;
        counter4--;
    }
}


    }
```

I know that I have a lot more I have to do but I just don't know how. Thanks for any support and help you guys can give me.

Comment: First step is to think about what you're trying to do.  You have 4 variables there, none of which has a name that actually indicates anything about what the variable is.  If you have something like "selectedNumber" and "currentNumber", then you'll want to print out the value of "currentNumber" a given number of times (specifically "selectedNumber - currentNumber + 1" times)

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int a;
    std::cout << "Enter an integer, any integer" << endl;

    if( cin >> a )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < a; i++ )
        {
            std::cout << std::string( i+1, '0'+a-i ) << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printPyramid(int n)
{
    if(n<=0)
    {
        return;
    }
    int i=1;
    for(int s=n;s>=1;s--)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            cout<<s;
        }
        cout<<endl;
        i++;
    }
}

int main ()
{
 printPyramid(5);
  return 0;
}
```